# Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to identify the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2x)$ as a product ring of two fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) to identify the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2x)$ as a product ring of two fields

$x^3 - 2x = x(x^2-2)$ and $\gcd(x, x^2-2) = 1$. So $x$ and $x^2-2$ are comaximal.

Then I can say that   $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2x) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/x(x^2-2) $is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/x \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ by using CRT.

Should I also prove that  $\mathbb{Q}[x]/x $ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ are fields?

Comment: $\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{(x)}\simeq \Bbb Q$ and $\frac{\Bbb Q[x]}{(x^2-2)}\simeq \Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ considering evaluation at $0$ and $\sqrt 2$ respectively.

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta looks neat. If I wrote in your way, does it imply more things?

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta hm.. I'm kinda stuck how you get that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2) $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$..

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474165/show-that-mathbbqx-x2%e2%88%922-is-a-field

Comment: Otherwise, consider the following lines: Let $f(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$ with $f(\sqrt 2)=0$. Write $f(x)=q(x)(x^2-2)+r(x)$ for some $q(x),r(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$ with either $r(x)=0$ or $\text{deg}(r(x))<\text{deg}(x^2-2)$, and for the latter case we can write $r(x)=ax+b$ for some $(a,b)\in \Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\backslash \{(0,0)\}$. But, $0=f(\sqrt 2)=q(\sqrt 2)\cdot 0+r(\sqrt2)\implies r(\sqrt 2)=0\implies a\sqrt 2+b=0$, a contradiction as $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Comment: From this conclude $(x^2-2)=\ker\big(\varphi:\Bbb Q[x]\ni f\longmapsto f(\sqrt 2)\in  \Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]\big)$.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ is a field: $(a+b\sqrt 2 )^{-1}=\frac{(a-b\sqrt 2)}{(a-b\sqrt 2 )(a+b\sqrt 2 )}=\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}$ for $(a,b)\in \Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q\backslash \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: A general fact you want to understand is that if $\alpha$ is the root of a polynomial $f$ over a field $F$ then $F(\alpha)\cong F[x]/(f(x))$. This is really fundamental in field theory.